# SQL Server insert into select from with inner join

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to move some data between two database tables with an insert into, select and inner join.

The query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Latitude, Longitude, GeoJSON)
(SELECT Table2.latitude, Table2.longitude, Table2.coordinates
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.CPGPlotCode = Table2.Code)
```

The query tells me that a number of rows are affected, but when I look at Table1, no information has been inserted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not showing an insert between two databases. Perhaps the issue lies within that fact. Do you have a Table1 in both databases? Perhaps you're looking in the wrong database?

Comment: If they are separate databases you haven't used another database in your query. You are probably inserting into a table on the wrong db.

Comment: Do both tables contain records and is there at least 1 record in table1 with a CPGPLOTcode that matches table2's code?  (if you just run the SELECT do you get any records?) `SELECT Table2.latitude, Table2.longitude, Table2.coordinates
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.CPGPlotCode = Table2.Code`  If the inner join is eliminating all the records the insert will run w/ no records inserted...  Post some sample data and expected results (based on the sample data) to your question so we can help you trouble shoot.

Comment: On a totally different track - you doing this inside a transaction? If so, did you commit it?

Comment: Both tables exist in the same database.